# Registering HttpHandler in ASP.NET MVC 3 and getting 404 Not Found Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, web-config, httphandler

I made a custom handler for test purposes, which looks like:

```
namespace MVCHttpHandlerProject
{
    public class SomeHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.Write("SomeHandler test");
        }
    }
}
```

Then I added to my **web.config** next lines:

`<httpHandlers>
<add path="SomeHandler.axd" verb="*" type="MVCHttpHandlerProject.SomeHandler, MVCHttpHandlerProject" /></httpHandlers>`

and in `<system.webServer>`

`<handlers>
      <add path="SomeHandler.axd" verb="*" type="MVCHttpHandlerProject.SomeHandler, MVCHttpHandlerProject" name="SomeHandler.axd"/>
    </handlers>`

My Global.asax.cs was not modified and looks exactly as when it was generated with `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` in RegisterRoutes method.

Still, when I try to get to "http://localhost/Home/SomeHandler.axd", "*The resource cannot be found*" error occurs. Why? Did I miss something? How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be requesting `http://localhost/SomeHandler.axd` instead of `http://localhost/Home/SomeHandler.axd`. There's no `Home`.

Comment: I wrongly assumed that {resource} in IgnoreRoute was supposed to deal with it. Then how do I make SomeHandler.axd called regardless of controller/area/everything in url before "/Somehandler.axd"?